# Docker Installation not working on Ubuntu x86_64 VM

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox

I'm trying to install lxc-docker on a Ubuntu 64 bit vdi.
Steps

1. I installed the VM using the pre-defined settings in virtualbox - and set up my VM to use the VDI I got. -> Ubuntu 17.10 10th-August build (64bit)
2. I did a sudo apt-get update. It worked fine
3. I did an sudo apt-get install lxc-docker - and it said unable to locate package lxc-docker.

I do a uname -i and I get back x86_64. I'm running my virtual box on windows 10, 64 bit.  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install docker.io`

Comment: I'm not completely sure what lxc-docker is. Are you looking for some special version, or do you just want regular Docker running on Ubuntu? The recommended way to install the most up-to-date version of Docker is to add the official Docker repository. Read about it here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Comment: docker.io worked last night. Thank you

Comment: I just wanted any version of docker to run on ubuntu - stackoverflow pointed me at lxc-docker which I thought was the one I needed to use

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guide as asked by @mkasberg, here's the summary from docker url

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up the repository for Ubuntu 17.10 first then install.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable"
```

Add Docker’s official GPG key:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then install

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce
```